# Enabling ssh at docker build time

Tags: docker, ansible

Docker version 17.11.0-ce, build 1caf76c

I need to run Ansible to build & deploy to wildfly some java projects during docker build time, so that when I run docker image I have everything setup. However, Ansible needs ssh to localhost. So far I was unable to make it working. I've tried different docker images and now I ended up with phusion (https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker#login_ssh). What I have atm:

```
FROM phusion/baseimage

# Use baseimage-docker's init system.
CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]

RUN rm -f /etc/service/sshd/down

# Regenerate SSH host keys. baseimage-docker does not contain any, so you
# have to do that yourself. You may also comment out this instruction; the
# init system will auto-generate one during boot.
RUN /etc/my_init.d/00_regen_ssh_host_keys.sh

RUN ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -N ''
RUN cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | tee -a ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN sed -i "s/#PermitRootLogin no/PermitRootLogin yes/" /etc/ssh/sshd_config && \
    exec ssh-agent bash && \
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

RUN /usr/sbin/sshd -d &

RUN ssh -tt root@127.0.0.1

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

But I still get

```
Step 11/12 : RUN ssh -tt root@127.0.0.1
 ---> Running in cf83f9906e55
ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused
The command '/bin/sh -c ssh -tt root@127.0.0.1' returned a non-zero code: 255
```

Any suggestions what could be wrong? Is it even possible to achieve that?

Comment: Why don't do all ssh steps in your host and share ~/.ssh/ directory as a volume?

Comment: @mulg0r you can't share a volume during build time.

Comment: You should give a chance to ansible-container. It is a tool to create docker images with Ansible instead of Dockerfile: https://github.com/ansible/ansible-container

Comment: And why don't do this when container starts? Why do you have to do it on build time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in that Dockerfile

First of all, you can't run a background process in a RUN statement and expect that process in another RUN. Each statement of a Dockerfile are run in a different containers so processes don't persist between them.

Other issue was that 127.0.0.1 is not in known_hosts.

And finally, you must give some time to sshd to start.

Here is a working Dockerfile:

```
FROM phusion/baseimage

CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]

RUN rm -f /etc/service/sshd/down

RUN /etc/my_init.d/00_regen_ssh_host_keys.sh

RUN ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -N ''
RUN cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | tee -a ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
RUN printf "Host 127.0.0.1\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n" >> ~/.ssh/config

RUN sed -i "s/#PermitRootLogin no/PermitRootLogin yes/" /etc/ssh/sshd_config && \
    exec ssh-agent bash && \
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

RUN /usr/sbin/sshd & sleep 5 && ssh -tt root@127.0.0.1 'ls -al'

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Anyway, I would rather find another solution than provisioning you image with Ansible in Dockerfile. Check out [ansible-container](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-container)

Answer (score 1):

```
RUN /usr/sbin/sshd -d &
```

That will run a process in the background using a shell. As soon as the shell that started the process returns from running the background command, it exits with no more input, and the container used for that RUN command terminates. The only thing saved from a RUN is the change to the filesystem. You do not save running processes, environment variables, or shell state.

Something like this may work, but you may also need a sleep command to give sshd time to finish starting.

```
RUN /usr/sbin/sshd -d & \
     ssh -tt root@127.0.0.1
```

I'd personally look for another way to do this without sshd during the build. This feels very kludgy and error prone.